# Asp Net Core Identity issue when switching to Production environment and Https

Tags: authentication, https, identity, production-environment, aspnetcore-environment

Everything works well on the development local machine (like usual!) but since I release a production version (=Environment Production) with HTTPS support, I am getting the following issue.

First click on login calls my usual login page:
[image: regular login page]

Then if I want to access a feature, the app asks me to login again using the default Asp Net Core Identity login page. What is weird is that I am already logged in as shown on the top right of the page:

[image: Default Identity login page when already logged in]

It is really not consistent :
Sometimes I can log in right away
Sometimes I have to log in with a second step using the default "Identity" login page (It is like a magic as I don't have such a page in my project!)
When I log out, I get a `nullreferenceobject` on the `httpcontext` - Maybe this is the clue.

This makes me think `httpcontext` is not set properly.
Below is my authentication config from startup.cs
:

```cs
#region Cookie options
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddCookie(options =>
     {
         options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
         options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = _environment.IsDevelopment()
           ? CookieSecurePolicy.None : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
         options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
     });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.Cookie.Name = "AuthCookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    // ReturnUrlParameter requires 
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = _environment.IsDevelopment()
      ? CookieSecurePolicy.None : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
#endregion

//This registers the various databases, either as in-memory or via SQL Server (see appsetting.json for connection strings)
var databaseSettings = new DatabaseSettings();
_configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings").Bind(databaseSettings);
services.RegisterDatabases(databaseSettings);


#region Identity Services

//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ItemUser>(options =>
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ExtraAuthorizeDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

// Register the Identity services.
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings.
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

    // Lockout settings.
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    // User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+?!&$€%";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

    // Default SignIn settings.
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
});

services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<ItemUser>, IpsumPasswordHasher>();

#region Page Authorization
services.AddMvc() //to avoid adding Authorize attribute to all pages model
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
        //Manage folder need to be logged in
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
        //Reset password doesn't need to logged in
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/ResetPassword");
        //Ask for checking email to validate email address
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/CheckEmail");
        //Message when Email has been confirmed
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/ConfirmEmail");
        //Authenticated on external login, ask for creating a backup account in the app
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/ExternalLogin");
        //Input Email to get a reset password email
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/ForgotPassword");
        //Ask for checking email to reset password
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        //User Profile
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/Index");
        //Notification that account is lock out
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/Lockout");
        //Login screen
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/Login");
        //Login when 2FA is enabled = seconde step after standard login
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/LoginWith2fa");
        //Login with recovery code = use recovery code if 2FA code not received
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/LoginWithRecoveryCode");
        //Notification log out successful
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/Logout");
        //Register as a new user
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/Register");

        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation");

        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/stripewebhook");
    });
#endregion
```

I don't know where to check to fix this. Thanks for any helping.